# Extracting relationship between two.sentences

Tags: stanford-nlp, information-extraction

I am looking for a algorithm which can help.me identify relationships between two sentences.
For example-
a. Planet revolves around stars.
b. Satellites revolve around planets. 
c. Sun is a star.
d. Earth revolves around sun.
e. Moon revolves around earth. 
Inference should be-
The Moon is a Satellite which revolves around Earth which is a Planet. Earth revolves around sun which is a star

Help me in this please
Thanks in advance